# React Native, why secureTextEntry not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Why is my `secureTextEntry` not working ? Here is my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={s.container}>
      <Input value='' placeholder='Passwort' style={[InputStyles.normal, s.inputMargin]} />
      <Input value={value} onChangeText={(e) => setValue(e)} placeholder='E-Mail' style={InputStyles.normal_icon} icon={<AntDesign name="stepforward" size={24} color="black" />} multiline secureTextEntry={true} keyboardType='default' />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`secureTextEntry` does not work with `multiline`. Here is what React Native’s [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#securetextentry) says:

> ## secureTextEntry
>
> If `true`, the text input obscures the text entered so that sensitive text like passwords stay secure. The default value is `false`. Does not work with `multiline={true}`.

In order to have it working, remove `multiline` propriety, like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={s.container}>
      <Input value='' placeholder='Passwort' style={[InputStyles.normal, s.inputMargin]} />
      <Input value={value} onChangeText={(e) => setValue(e)} placeholder='E-Mail' style={InputStyles.normal_icon} icon={<AntDesign name="stepforward" size={24} color="black" />} secureTextEntry={true} keyboardType='default' />
    </View>
  );
}
```